# queue.deque for gcp tasks using firebase-admin-sdk

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-admin

```js
    const { getFunctions } = require("firebase-admin/functions");
    const queue = getFunctions().taskQueue(queue-name);
    queue.enqueue(payload, {
        scheduleDelaySeconds,
        dispatchDeadlineSeconds: 60 * 5
    })
```

In firebase-admin-sdk there is this part that is used to create tasks in gcp. But is there any queue.deque in firebase-admin-sdk to handle gcp task deletion?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can only enqueue tasks using the Firebase Admin Node.js SDK. There is a [feature request](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/1753) for additional functionality on the `firebase-admin-node` Github repo. Additional features are not in the immediate roadmap plan, but we will use the Github issue to track any progress on this. Thanks!